# Flutter | Carousel Slider error when setting the enlargeCenterPage to true,

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have implemented an Image Slider with the package **carousel_slider: ^2.3.1**. Everything works fine. But when I set the **enlargeCenterProperty** on Options to **true**, the debugger catches this error.

[image]

```
CarouselSlider(
                              carouselController: CarouselController(),
                              items: <Widget>[
                                Container(height:100),
                                Container(height:100),
                                Container(height:100),
                              ],
                              options: CarouselOptions(
                                  //when this line is commented the error vanishes
                                  enlargeCenterPage: true,
                                  height: 180.0,
                                  enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.scale,
                                  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                                  autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                                  enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                                  autoPlayAnimationDuration:
                                      Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                                  viewportFraction: 0.8,
                                  initialPage: 0,
                                  autoPlay: true),
                            )
```

Comment: have you got solution for this? I am getting Null check operator used on null value error